# CSS animate text to image

Tags: css, image, animation, text

The effect that I'm looking to obtain is the user first sees the hint text without the arrow and then the text shrinks down to 0% width and you will just see the arrow instead. The container should also only have enough space to barely fit the text inside of it with a  little bit of padding. Don't know if that is explained clearly enough. So the container shrinks the fit the size of the content and the content changes from text to image after a certain amount of time.

Here is my HTML below.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ScrollDownArrow">
    <div class="Relative">

        <div class="Hint">
            <p>Skip to next section</p>
            <img src="Assets/IMG/"INSERT ARROW IMG HERE".png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}

.Hint
{
    display: block;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    border:2px solid  #f6473e;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -wbkit-border-radius: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  margin 0.8s ease 2.6s ,  padding 0.8s ease 2.6s;
    -o-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  margin 0.8s ease 2.6s,  padding 0.8s ease 2.6s;
    -moz-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  margin 0.8s ease 2.6s,  padding 0.8s ease 2.6s;
    -webkit-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  margin 0.8s ease 2.6s,  padding 0.8s ease 2.6s;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 20px;
}


.Hint.Show
{


}
.Hint.Show p
{
    display:inline-block;

}
.Hint p
{
    color:#000;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display:none;
    transition: width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  opacity 0.8s ease 2s;
    -o-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  opacity 0.8s ease 2s;
    -moz-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  opacity 0.8s ease 2s;
    -webkit-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  opacity 0.8s ease 2s;
    }
.Hint.Show img
{
    display:none;
}
.Hint img
{

    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    max-width:38px;
    transition: width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  opacity 0.8s ease 2s;
    -o-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  opacity 0.8s ease 2s;
    -moz-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  opacity 0.8s ease 2s;
    -webkit-transition:  width 0.8s ease 2.6s,  opacity 0.8s ease 2s;
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform:translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
}

.ScrollDownArrow
{
    display: block;
    height: 38px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform:translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: bottom 0.8s ease 1.6s, width 0.8s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: bottom 0.8s ease 1.6s, width 0.8s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: bottom 0.8s ease 1.6s, width 0.8s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 0.8s ease 1.6s, width 0.8s ease 0s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ScrollDownArrow').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('Clicked')){
            $(this).removeClass('Clicked');
            $('.Hint').removeClass('Show');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('Clicked');   
            $('.Hint').addClass('Show'); 
        }

    });
});
```

Would be ideal if the hint was surrounded by a border and the whole container shrinks to fit the text inside and the text can also change in width so I cannot use fixed width.

Here's a fiddle which I just made which is pretty close to the code I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/bfh55npj/3/ the problem is, the width isn't transitioning and instead just snapping to the width it needs.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/bfh55npj/6/ updated the fiddle with the answer I was looking for in case anybody else wants to use it. The effect doesn't work too well in reverse but the effect I want only needs to work in one way, so that's fine and I have accounted for the reverse and it's only there for display purposes so you can do the animation again without refreshing.

Comment: And your best attempt so far was what, exactly? How far did you get, where, and *how*, did it fail?

Comment: I've just added a fiddle so you can see what it kinda looks like, main problem I'm facing is the elements inside the hint I believe need to positioned absolute so they cannot get the width they need. Perhaps there is a way around this?

Comment: Thanks, now: could you add the relevant code into your question, so it's immediately available to those that may want to try and help you? Also, clearly articulate exactly what you want to happen in response to what event(s); assume that we know nothing of your intent because, seriously, we *don't*, until you tell us.

Comment: I've added all the code from the fiddle, I thought I already explained what I wanted to happen but just in case it wasn't clear the fiddle should be a good example to look at. So when you click on the button the image disappears and the arrow appears instead. I want this effect to be smoother so the width transitions and the text and arrow transition instead of immediately moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this Jquery-code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ScrollDownArrow").click(function(){
        if($(".ScrollDownArrow").hasClass("Clicked")){
           $(".Hint img").fadeOut(500); 
           $(".Hint p").delay(500)/*wait on fadeout*/.animate({width: 200} /*Unfortunately width: 100% does not seem to work so I took a px value :(*/, 1000).animate({opacity:1}, 500); 
           $(".ScrollDownArrow").removeClass("Clicked");
        }else{
           $(".Hint p").animate({opacity:0.01}/*fade p out without making its width disappear for the width animation*/, 500).animate({width: 0}, 1000);
           $(".Hint img").delay(1500).fadeIn(500);
           $(".ScrollDownArrow").addClass("Clicked");
        }
    }); // End Click
});//End Ready
```

You can put the width value at 100% in the Jquery-script if you want to make the width fit the paragraph, but unfortunately the animation seems to fail if you do that. I ll start a new question to see if somebody knows a fix for that.

I also removed the css-animations since we are using jquery and using both at once is kind of confusing. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfh55npj/4/).

Comment: I create a workaround for the problem here is the new JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfh55npj/5/

Comment: I've just updated my fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/bfh55npj/6/ and it looks pretty similar to what you've done although I'm still using CSS transition as I believe they're faster than jQuery animate. I also found a different function that calculates the width of the text inside the paragraph that you might find helpful.

Comment: The transition from text to image looks a bit weird. Besides that I ll look around in your code a bit since I might learn something new myself ^^